# Can't understand the binding issue

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js

I've been working with this type of binding (using knockout.js) a while ago and everything worked fine, but today a new issue arose. Namely:

I have a rather complex view model that has "parts" that are based on a certain process parameter. The entire viewmodel is "bound" to the page, but any process only ever uses its own parts. To put it simply, imagine this is your viewmodel:

```
{
    1: Object (actual view model)
    2: Object (actual view model)
    3: Object (actual view model)
    6: Object (actual view model)
    getModelData = function(paramNumber) //returns the view model)
    extractJSObject = function(paramNumber) //console.logs a "JS" object
}
```

Now, the usual data-bind syntax in most tutorials follows something along the lines of:

`<input data-bind="value: displayedValue">`

And a view model with an observable named displayedValue is present in the view model. The syntax that I am using however follows these rules however:

`<input data-bind="value: getModelData( processID ).DataSets.  nameOfDataSet   ()[ indexOfDataElement ].  fieldName">`

to give you an example:
`<input data-bind="value: getModelData(1).DataSets.Countries()[0].CountryPhoneCode">`

Now, for some reason, this doesn't seem to work, where previously it used to work. Mainly **the getModelData() function** exists within a viewModel that is bound to the HTML and it does return whatever it needs to so don't be confused by this, its a regular binding, just as if you were to bind any other object, but I am assuming somewhere along the lines later on something gets #@#cked.

The image shows the console error message, as well as my two lines of code which return the expected results, why does my own typing in console work properly but the model is still not being able to bind itself is beyond me.

[image]

**EDIT:** One last thing, in the HTML the binding is not as shown as error in the console, the binding is exactly like this:

`<input data-bind="value: getModelData(6).DataSets.HumanUser()[0].Address">`

Comment: Is any of your data loaded asynchronously? I'm curious if the binding is firing before the data exists, but once you check in the console it's had time to load.

Comment: Also what version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Normally, in this situation, I'd right click the element in the UI whose view model I want to examine, select "inspect", then use `ko.dataFor($0)` to see exactly what is there.  In your case, it would be `ko.dataFor($0).getModelData(6).DataSets.HumanUser()[0].Address`  to see exactly what knockout sees (rather than make any assumptions whatsoever)

Comment: What happens if you add `data-bind="text: console.log(getModelData(6)"` prior to the binding?

Comment: @JasonSpake the data is loaded asynchronously, but the binding is done after the data is loaded. AJAX response to the request that gets the data in a JSON file is to "bind it". Until that request's response is received there is no binding done. Verson of jQuery, idk would have to check (will report back in an hour or so once I have access, i believe it was 3.xomething.something, used to run just fine with that same version - using local file instead of a CDN so shouldnt be an issue)

Comment: @Will will check that, was not aware that there is such a command, reporting back in an hour or so, once I have access to the files. Though knockout 'fails and throws an error" so I doubt it sees anything, but worth a shot.

Comment: @JohnPavek I doubt anything happens, will check in an hour or so once i have access to the files. Having anything in data-bind doesn't really do anything afaik until you attempt to bind it. Once you do attempt to bind it however it should get evaluated, though `console.log` has no return value so I'd assume there would be noting to bind and an error should be thrown, I might be wrong in the assumption, will try and return with results

Comment: @JasonSpake ok so an update, JQuery was apparently not local, the version used earlier, when it worked was acquired from here: `<script src=\"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js\"></script>` which I assume is 1.12. The recent changes however have us switched to: `<script src=\"https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js\" integrity=\"sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n\" crossorigin=\"anonymous\"></script>`

Which was caused by the transition from bootstrap 3 to boostrap 4. Now what changed in jQuery is beyond me.

Comment: @JasonSpake to further talk on the matter. I downloaded the newest version of knockout and am using the jquery from bootstrap4's cdn (so 3.1.1). The result is the same error. If I disable the jquery, no error is thrown. Seems that jQuery and Knockout.js somehow conflict even though the official website for knockout says they do not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery deprecated [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) in 3.0 when the Slim version was also released, but it seems that Knockout still assumes `.bind` exists when jQuery is present so when you *do* have an include for jQuery it needs to be the full jQuery not the slim version. The difference being that the slim version of jquery "excludes ajax, effects, and *currently deprecated code*" [-reference](https://blog.jquery.com/2016/06/09/jquery-3-0-final-released/)

Comment: It seemed to have worked with the bootstrap's CDN optained slim version, had it working for couple of hours, though now I am assuming it was probably just cached version of the page being delivered that had NO version at all. That said I have downloaded a full minified version and am keeping it as a file on the server instead of using a CDN and seems to be working for now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Okay so since I fiddled around with versions of libraries that are being used and the order in which they are used here is the conclusion:

1. Knockout.js does not require jQuery for it to function, it works fine without it, matter of fact, as soon as i removed any jQuery the page started working and binding worked.
2. If however jQuery is present, it must be loaded BEFORE knockout.js because otherwise this error occurs. An exception to this rule is on #3
3. Old versions of jQuery do not conflict for some reason, even if loaded after knockout.js, but any newer version needs to be loaded beforehand.

Ordering the scripts like:
 1. jQuery
 2. knockout
 3. bootstrap
Made it all work nicely, thanks for all the assistance and direction you made me look at.

**EDIT: well... apparently it was working for about an hour, aaaand now no longer works o.0 I really thought I got to the end of it.**

**EDIT 2: apparently server was delivering a cached version which didnt have any jQuery at all from the time i was removing it. The correct answer and the reason is marked as "answered" Thanks all.**

Comment: It's probably more work than you want to do, but I had a similar page where the view model contained sub view models. It helped a ton to refactor it all into individual components. Even if I wasn't reusing them. Your situation might be worth it if they don't need to talk to each other.

Comment: Sadly they do so i have this whole web of data cross calling shiet, its a mess. But, works for now, so i dont wanna 'poke the bear'